# How to include variables within #+INCLUDE:?

Tags: org-mode, variables

In my init file, all the paths that I use are stored at the beginning of the file with a series of lines like this:

```
(setq personal-path "PATH")
```

Then I can use them like this:

```
(set-register ?s (cons 'file (concat personal-path  "somefile.org")))
```

Now I'm trying to use these variables with `#+INCLUDE:`, but it's not working.

When I do

```
#+INCLUDE: (concat personal-path "somefile.org::sometable")
```

The HTML export fails.

Comment: That's not particularly surprising: `#+INCLUDE` takes a path as its first parameter, not an s-expression. There are a few places where Org mode allows s-expressions and it evaluates them in certain contexts (e.g. that used to be the case certain places in capture templates, when you did a capture; although that particular facility does not exist any longer, a similar facility when defining variables in a source block header is still present and is triggered when you evaluate the source block). There is no such facility for the first parameter of `#+INCLUDE`, so you cannot do what you want ...

Comment: ... not, in any case, in any straightforward way. I think the best you can do is preprocess the buffer to evaluate the s-exprsessions and replace them with the result strings. You might be able to use the `org-export-before-parsing-hook` for that: see [Advanced Export Configuration](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration) in the Org mode manual for some information, although it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: So I cannot put Elisp variables... But as far as I understand it Org-Mode also has its own variables. For example, for links, there is abbreviated org-link. However, they only seem to work within links.

Comment: Isn't there a type of variable, even org specific, whatever it is, that I can set in the init and use within `#+INCLUDE:`?

Comment: Not that I know of. I wondered if you could use macros but macros are expanded *after* the `#+INCLUDE`s are processed.

Comment: In this case, I will use org-transclusion instead of `#+INCLUDE`. I just hope their link format accepts abbreviated org-links.

Comment: FYI `org-link-abbrev-alist` works well with `#+transclude`.

Comment: Great! Maybe you can provide an answer to your own question then.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible to use variables with `#+INCLUDE:`.

However, [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion), which is a package that lets you insert a copy of some content via a file link or ID link within an Org file, can read [link abbreviations](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Abbreviations.html).

So if you install `org-transclusion`, you can add this line in your init :

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist (list (cons "personal-org-path" personal-path)))
```

And then write the following line in your org file

```
#+transclude:: [[personal-org-path:somefile.org::sometable]]
```